# re.findall not outputting group right

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to get all the text after the word "does" in a string.. But I'm only getting the first letter after the word "does"..

```
string=str("does he like") 
A=re.findall(r'^does\s([\w+\s+])',string ,re.IGNORECASE)
for tuple in A:
    print tuple[0]
```

The output of that code just gives "h", but I want "he like". Can anyone see what's wrong with my code? There might be an easier way but I want to use the re.findall thing. I'm kind of new to python and to posting on this site.. So go easy on me.. Thanks

Oh and this is python 2.7 by the way..

Comment: The `+` inside a character class matches a literal `+`. You wanted to use `r'^does\s([\w\s]+)'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
s = "does he like"
p = re.compile(r"[^does(n't)?].+")
print(''.join(p.findall(s, re.IGNORECASE)))
```

or this, if you want just `he likes`:

```
r'\s.+'
```

Comment: `r'^does.+'` matches `"doesn't"`

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This captures the entire string but using group(1) which is you using tuple[0] with grab every word after 'does'.

```
A = re.findall(r'^does (.*)', string ,re.IGNORECASE)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit, I would recommend using `\s` to represent whitespace.

Comment: OP is using `findall` which returns a string or a tuple, not a `match` obect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out:

```
r'(?<=does\s)([\w\s-]+)'
```

[Trial #1 at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/thBl28/2)

Which matches all letters, dashes, spaces and digits after `does` until a special character like `?` or `.`

If you want **everything** after the word `does`, then use this:

```
r'(?<=does\s)(.+)'
```

[Trial #2 at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/thBl28/3)

## Regex -

`(?<=does\s)` is a positive look-behind which ensures that the match is preceded by "does" and a space.

`[\w\s-]+` matches one-or-more letters, digits, spaces or dashes.

[Here's a full summary of the above regexes](https://repl.it/repls/ImmaculateWonderfulCurrencies).

Comment: OP is using `findall` so only put the stuff you want to capture in a group.

Comment: @tdelaney Could you elaborate on that? I've tried using findall with my regex, and it executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first is that `[]` matches a single character in the given group. You asked for a single word, space or plus sign. The second is that when you only have a single capture group, `findall` returns a string, not a tuple. Move the plus out of the character group and use the matched string directly.

```
import re

string=str("does he like") 
A=re.findall(r'^does\s([\w\s]+)',string ,re.IGNORECASE)
for foo in A:
    print foo
```